# special tiling of matrix in tensorflow or numpy

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, array-broadcasting, tiling

Consider 3D tensor of T(w x h x d).

The goal is to create a tensor of R(w x h x K) where K = d x k by tiling along 3rd dimension in a unique way.

The tensor should repeat each slice in 3rd dimension k times, meaning :

```
T[:,:,0]=R[:,:,0:k] and T[:,:,1]=R[:,:,k:2*k]
```

There's a subtle difference with standard tiling which gives `T[:,:,0]=R[:,:,::k]`, repeats at every kth in 3rd dimension.

Comment: So, did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.repeat` along that axis -

```
np.repeat(T,k,axis=2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [688]: # Setup
     ...: w,h,d = 2,3,4
     ...: k = 2
     ...: T = np.random.randint(0,9,(w,h,d))
     ...: 
     ...: # Original approach
     ...: R = np.zeros((w,h,d*k),dtype=T.dtype)
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     R[:,:,i*k:(i+1)*k] = T[:,:,i][...,None]
     ...:  

In [692]: T
Out[692]: 
array([[[4, 5, 6, 4],
        [5, 4, 4, 3],
        [8, 0, 0, 8]],

       [[7, 3, 8, 0],
        [8, 7, 0, 8],
        [3, 6, 8, 5]]])


In [690]: R
Out[690]: 
array([[[4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3],
        [8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8]],

       [[7, 7, 3, 3, 8, 8, 0, 0],
        [8, 8, 7, 7, 0, 0, 8, 8],
        [3, 3, 6, 6, 8, 8, 5, 5]]])

In [691]: np.allclose(R, np.repeat(T,k,axis=2))
Out[691]: True
```

Alternatively with `np.tile` and `reshape` -

```
np.tile(T[...,None],k).reshape(w,h,-1)
```

Comment: No need to reshape. `np.repeat` takes an `axis` parameter.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup, was over-complicating. Thanks, edited.

Comment: Thanks. Just came across the np.repeat. However, there's no counterpart in tensorflow for the same

Comment: @user2527599 What about [tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile)?

Comment: @user2527599 So, did the posted solution work for you?